# Keep 24h for each day when resampling `pandas` `Series` (from daily to hourly)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `pandas` `Series` with a (tz-localized) `DateTimeIndex` with one value per day:

```
tmpr
Out[38]: 
2018-01-01 00:00:00+01:00    1.810
2018-01-02 00:00:00+01:00    2.405
2018-01-03 00:00:00+01:00    1.495
2018-01-04 00:00:00+01:00    1.600
2018-01-05 00:00:00+01:00    0.545

2020-12-27 00:00:00+01:00    2.655
2020-12-28 00:00:00+01:00    1.705
2020-12-29 00:00:00+01:00    1.255
2020-12-30 00:00:00+01:00    1.405
2020-12-31 00:00:00+01:00    3.000
Freq: D, Name: tmpr, Length: 1096, dtype: float64
```

which I want to upsample to hourly values, so that each value is repeated 24 times (or 23 or 25, depending on summer/wintertime changeover, but that's a whole other story). Here's what I tried:

```
tmpr.resample('h').ffill()
Out[39]: 
2018-01-01 00:00:00+01:00    1.810
2018-01-01 01:00:00+01:00    1.810
2018-01-01 02:00:00+01:00    1.810
2018-01-01 03:00:00+01:00    1.810
2018-01-01 04:00:00+01:00    1.810

2020-12-30 20:00:00+01:00    1.405
2020-12-30 21:00:00+01:00    1.405
2020-12-30 22:00:00+01:00    1.405
2020-12-30 23:00:00+01:00    1.405
2020-12-31 00:00:00+01:00    3.000
Freq: H, Name: tmpr, Length: 26281, dtype: float64
```

**The problem is the final day: I can't get  `resample` to include the 23 hours after `0:00`.**

Adding a `closed` parameter doesn't make a difference, neither when resampling, nor when creating the original timeseries.

(I've tried creating the original `Series` with a left or a right-closed index: `pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 1), end=pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 1), freq='D', closed='left')` and `... end=pd.Timestamp(2020, 12, 31)`, but the resulting Series seems the same.)

I could always append an additinal day (2021-01-01) with a dummy value, and then remove it at the end, but that's terribly hacky.

Any ideas on how to do this the way it was intended?

PS - In a previous project, using a `PeriodIndex` instead of a `DateTimeIndex`, I had no problems. However, I cannot use that here as those do not support time zone functionality, which I do need.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is daily, you can do just create new timestamps and `reindex`:

```
new_timestamps = pd.date_range(tmpr.index[0], 
                          tmpr.index[-1]+pd.to_timedelta('23H'),
                          freq='H')

tmpr.reindex(new_timestamps).ffill()
```

Output (for the first half of your sample data):

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00+01:00    1.810
2018-01-01 01:00:00+01:00    1.810
2018-01-01 02:00:00+01:00    1.810
2018-01-01 03:00:00+01:00    1.810
2018-01-01 04:00:00+01:00    1.810
                             ...  
2018-01-05 19:00:00+01:00    0.545
2018-01-05 20:00:00+01:00    0.545
2018-01-05 21:00:00+01:00    0.545
2018-01-05 22:00:00+01:00    0.545
2018-01-05 23:00:00+01:00    0.545
Freq: H, Name: tmpr, Length: 120, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I changed it a bit to `new_timestamps = pd.date_range(tmpr.index[0], tmpr.index[-1] + pd.to_timedelta('1day'), freq='H', closed='left')`, and it's working. But still don't find it very appealing compared to a simple `.resample()`